# Reboot linux laptop from the command line gracefully

Tags: command-line, xorg, kde

In a script, I want to reboot my linux  laptop like the reboot button in the KDE GUI. If there is a program open with unsaved files, those programs show a message, "do you want to save your files?".

I have tried `reboot` and even `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot" boolean:true`, but they just reboot after killing all programs without confirmation

Comment: This might be of interest: https://superuser.com/a/396091

Comment: @arkascha that worked. First I tried it with sudo which did not work, but without sudo and setting $DISPLAY it did work